# Remove white strip above Image

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My database looks like this:

[image]

Now I want to get the Value of "ImageUrl"
How to do this?
Actually, I only have this:

```
String imageUrl = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("users/").child(userid).child("ImageUrl")...and than?
```

How to continue this line? I only found solutions with AddValueEventListener, but I think that's not the right for this Situation because I only want to get the String of "ImageUrl".

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("users").child(userid).child("imageUrl")
                      .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String imageUrl = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("Url", imageUrl);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
retrievedata = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");

retrievedata.child(userid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {//to retrieve data
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String url = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
            Picasso.with(Activity_name.this).load(url).into(image);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Picasso is a library to display the image on the screen.
load(url) , the String that you will load

into(image), this is the imageview where the image will be in

example ImageView **image**=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);